# Is it a idiomatic to implicitly make a class convertible to bool?

Tags: python

For some reason a lot of types are implicitly convertible to boolean values, despite Python's "be explicit" guideline. Anyway...

Is it idiomatic to make custom classes also implicitly convertible to bool, where appropriate? If yes, what function should I (re)define? In my specific case, I have an `Image` class; I want to make it convertible to bool such that it is `True` when it is holds data loaded from somewhere (a file), and `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *can* be idiomatic; e.g., container object should test false when they are empty. You should define [`__nonzero__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) in Python 2.x and [`__bool__`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) in Python 3 to do the conversion. When writing code targeting Python 2 and 3, define both.

However, in keeping with the "explicit is better than implicit" guideline, you might instead want to just say `if img.is_loaded():` instead. The main reason `__nonzero__`/`__bool__` exists is for containers, which is reflected in its description in The Python Data model: "When this method is not defined, `__len__()` is called, if it is defined, and the object is considered true if its result is nonzero." So it's really shorthand for `len(obj) == 0`, perhaps implemented with a faster check.